# Python: multithreading setting the variable once

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

Does the following code thread-safe?
Will only one/first thread set the variable, set_this_var_only_once?

```
set_this_var_only_once = None

def worker():
    global set_this_var_only_once
    if set_this_var_only_once is None:
        set_this_var_only_once = "not None"

for i in range(10):
    t = threading.Thread( target=worker )
    t.daemon=True
    t.start()
```

Comment: What if two or more workers check the condition before either of them sets the variable?

Comment: @machineyearning that is my worry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely not.

It is quite possible that two threads execute this line before executing the next one:

```
    if set_this_var_only_once is None:
```

After that, both threads will execute the next line:

```
        set_this_var_only_once = "not None"
```

You can use [locks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock) to prevent that:

```
lock = threading.Lock()

def worker():
    lock.acquire()
    if set_this_var_only_once is None:
        set_this_var_only_once = "not None"
    lock.release()
```

Only one thread will be able to *acquire* the lock. If another thread tries to acquire it while it is locked, the call to `lock.acquire()` will block and wait until the lock is *released* by the first thread. Then the lock will be acquired by the other thread.

That way it is ensured that the code between `lock.acquire()` and `lock.release()` is executed in one thread at a time.

**EDIT**

As Gerhard pointed in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40100334/389289), you can use the [context management protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#with-locks) with locks:

```
with lock:
    if set_this_var_only_once is None:
        set_this_var_only_once = "not None"
```

That will also make sure the lock is correctly released in case of an exception within the locked block.

Answer (score 4):

You need to lock the variable like this:

```
from threading import Lock

lock = Lock()
set_this_var_only_once = None

def worker():
    with lock:
        if set_this_var_only_once is None:
            set_this_var_only_once = "not None
```

Comment: Using `with` is a nice touch ;)

Comment: Makes the code more clear and it's practically identical with Java's synchronized blocks, i.e. synchronized(lock) { /*code*/ }.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not.

> If another thread gets control after the current thread has fetched
>   the variable, it may fetch the variable, increment it, and write it
>   back, before the current thread does the same thing. And since they’re
>   both seeing the same original value, only one item will be accounted
>   for.

[Here's](http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm) this good article about it.

P.S. Also the following line is needed in the worker():

```
global set_this_var_only_once
```